# Wordpress Frontend Check If Current User Is Administrator

Tags: admin, front-end

I am trying to check if current user that accessing a page if administrator using `current_user_can()`, but it is not working and returning this message instead:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in /home/******/public_html/wordpress/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1329
```

What can I use to check whether a user is admin or not in the front end?

I am using a separate php file to do it, like this:

```
<?php
    if(current_user_can('manage_options')) {
    // do stuff here..
    }
?>
```

I know it can be fixed by adding this line of code `require_once('pluggable.php')` in the second line of file named `capabilities.php`. But I don't want user bothering about it.

Comment: Where are you calling the function?

Comment: @birgire In frontend. It's also not working in administration page..

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you calling the function within the functions.php file? If so then what action hook are you using? Or do you call it from another theme file? Can you share the relevant code snippet?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: You don't want to edit a core file. It looks like you're calling the WordPress function within an external PHP file. I wonder if you can include your external file as a plugin instead?

Comment: I agree with @bravokeyl's answer. It totally depends on at what point in the WordPress action process you are calling the file. Your question doesn't really say.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the function is not defined at the point of calling your code ..so wrap the code of yours in to a function and hook it to the `init`.